# Setting Proxy for HttpClient in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I'm trying to set a proxy to HttpClient in UWP
but I can't find any class that implement IWebProxy that I can provide to the HttpClientHandler object

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to specify a custom proxy for the `HttpClient` class.

From [this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/) article:

> For both APIs, proxy settings are automatically obtained from Internet Explorer/Microsoft Edge settings and are used for all the HTTP calls by default. This enables apps to automatically work even if the user is connected to the internet through a proxy. **Neither API provides a way to specify a custom proxy for your app.** However, you can choose to not use the default proxy by setting HttpClientHandler.UseProxy to false (for System.Net.Http) or HttpBaseProtocolFilter.UseProxy to false (for Windows.Web.Http).

Comment: But IOT does not have browser, MSFT this sucks :(

Comment: You might be able to set it with PowerShell, though I haven't tried it myself... Check here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-function-Get-cba2abf5